# how to pass parameters to external webservice in mvc3

Tags: jquery, web-services

webservice is like this
i took this in partialview

```
 <form action="www.xyz/x/y" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="abc" value="40" />
<input type="button" id="btn"/>
   />
```

when i click button that output for webservice will be like this.
`abc:40`
i have a variable in jscript with value some 80. every time it will change like it multiplies with 1,2 when we select 1,2. 
now when i click button that value should change. like `abc:80` `abc:160`

how can i pass this variable.?

Comment: **finally i got the answer. its simple  
giving id to hidden field
<input type="hidden" name="abc" value="40"  id="hid"/>

`$("#selector").val(variable_name);` **

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer. its simple
giving id to hidden field

`$("#selector").val();`